# Problem with calculating and writing silence

Tags: c#, audio, ffmpeg

Because Discord sends no audio if user isn't talking, I need to calculate time after their latest voice data received and write some amout of silence to the buffer. I have this code for handling audio data:

```
private async Task OnVoiceReceived(VoiceNextConnection sender, VoiceReceiveEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!_isRecording) return;
        
        if (e.User is null) return;

        if (!_circularBuffers.TryGetValue(e.User.Id, out var circularBuffer))
        {
            circularBuffer = new CircularBuffer(e.AudioFormat.SampleRate * e.AudioFormat.ChannelCount * 2 * _bufferDurationSeconds, 
                e.AudioFormat.ChannelCount);
            _circularBuffers[e.User.Id] = circularBuffer;
        }

        TimeSpan delay;

        if (!_lastVoiceActivity.TryGetValue(e.User.Id, out var lastData))
        {
            // If we don't have any data for this user, we assume that last data from this user was received at the same time as recording started
            delay = DateTimeOffset.Now - _recordingStartedAt;
        }
        else delay = DateTimeOffset.Now - lastData;

        // calculate how much silence we need to add to the buffer
        var silence = new byte[e.AudioFormat.SampleRate * e.AudioFormat.ChannelCount * 2 * (int)Math.Round(delay.TotalSeconds)];
        
        await circularBuffer.WriteAsync(silence);

        _lastVoiceActivity[e.User.Id] = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        
        
        await circularBuffer.WriteAsync(e.PcmData);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Error(exception, "Error while receiving voice data");
    }
}
```

After the recording finishes, with ffmpeg I write buffers to .wav files and then mix audios.

I have a problem that sometimes amount of silence is wrong and espacially this can be heard after mixing audios of multiple users. Sometimes amount of silence is not enough and somtimes it's too long. For example, In conversation recording user 1 can respond to user 2 even before user 2 asks him or vice-versa, user 1 can respond too late. Also I found that the problem appears often after some data of the buffer was removed due to overfilling.

I tried to change formula to calculate silence, and add data duration when setting new value of `_lastVoiceActivity` but that just made the problem worse. Also I tried to add silence only if delay is more than 100ms but this also didn't help. For testing I use circular buffers which can contain 30 seconds of audio.

I use DSharpPlus for Discord and ffmpeg for mixing audios.

**UPD**: I found that if I don't remove data from buffers due to overfilling, the probles becomes almost invisible. So here is my CircularBuffer implementation:

```
    public class CircularBuffer
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<byte> _buffer;
    
    private readonly object _lockObject;
    private readonly int _bufferSize;

    public int Channels { get; private set; }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                return _buffer.Count;
            }
        }
    }

    public CircularBuffer(int size, int channels)
    {
        _buffer = new ConcurrentQueue<byte>();
        _bufferSize = size;
        Channels = channels;
        _lockObject = new object();
    }

    public async Task WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> data)
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            if (data.Length > _bufferSize) data = data[^_bufferSize..];

            if (_buffer.Count + data.Length > _bufferSize)
            {
                var bytesToRemove = _buffer.Count + data.Length - _bufferSize;
                
                for (var i = 0; i < bytesToRemove; i++)
                {
                    _buffer.TryDequeue(out _);
                }
            }
            
            for (var index = 0; index < data.Span.Length; index++)
            {
                var b = data.Span[index];
                _buffer.Enqueue(b);
            }
        }
        
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    
    public async Task ReadAsync(Memory<byte> data)
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            if (data.Length > _buffer.Count)
            {
                data = data[.._buffer.Count];
            }
            
            for (var index = 0; index < data.Span.Length; index++)
            {
                _buffer.TryDequeue(out var b);
                data.Span[index] = b;
            }
        }

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            _buffer.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```